# Integration between Salesforce CRM Anaytics with Mulesoft

Tags: salesforce, mulesoft, mule4, mule-esb, salesforce-rest-api

We want to fetch the data from DataSet present in Salesforce CRM Analytics and insert the same data into the database using Mulesoft. Currently we are exporting the DataSet in a CSV using a recipe that creates an external Salesforce object and then we are querying that external object to fetch the data in parts, but now we're stuck because the size of our data is above 50 GB and when we are trying to export the data the whole full load data we are getting an error saying we are exceeding the maximum amount of data that is 50 GB per day.

Can I use Salesforce REST API to fetch records from DataSet?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can query datasets, using Mulesoft, from CRM Analytics. You can use /services/data/v58.0/wave/query enpoint. In Mulesoft you just need to use HTTP Request connector with POST method. In the payload you set the SAQL statement - same as you would use it in a lens.
The volume of data you have is huge - so maybe you should use a watermark with a scheduler that takes the newest data only.

Answer (score 0):

Visit: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.content_file_size_limits.htm&type=5

Note the 50GB limit: "default delivery bandwidth per rolling 24-hour window".

Then:

1. Create a Salesforce support ticket including an explanation of what you're doing
2. If they approve they will provide you a an exemption request form.
3. In the form you designate a start date and end date for the exemption and information about your project

Servicing your request might require that your company leadership expedite the request.